# for loop in r with two condition to find the sum of difference

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a code that has Two condition

```
function1 <- function(x,y){
x<- c(3,4,7)
y<-c(1,2,7)
diffsum<-0
for (i in 1:length(x))
  for(j in 1:length(y)){
    diffsum <- diffsum+(x[i]-y[j])
  }
return(diffsum)
}

function1(x,y)
[1] 12
```

loking for (3-1)+(4-2)+(7-7)
the result should be 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `sum(x-y)`. No need for any loop here.

If it has to be a loop:

```
function1 <- function(x,y)
{
  difftime <- 0
    
  for (i in 1:length(x))
  {
    loop_diff <- x[i] - y[i]
    difftime <- difftime + loop_diff
  }
  return(difftime)
}
```

Comment: you are right, but I'm trying to learn loops and taking this function as an example to apply it to other data.

Comment: Well, it is a bad example for practicing double loops then. If any, it could be done in a single loop.